# Create hibernate criteria to show result as this query

Tags: hibernate

Hi Please below table and query. This taken from someone else's post but its exactly as I needed. 
I want to create Hibernate Criteria (No HQL or SQL) that produce same result as sql does below this table.

Any idea how to make it?

Here is I tried but its not correct way.

```
criteria.setProjection(
        Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("train"))
        .add(Projections.max("time"))
        .add(Property.forName("train").group())
        );
```

TrainTable

```
Train    Dest      Time
1        HK        10:00
1        SH        12:00
1        SZ        14:00
2        HK        13:00
2        SH        09:00
2        SZ        07:00
```

SQL

```
SELECT t.Train, t.Dest, r.MaxTime
FROM (
      SELECT Train, MAX(Time) as MaxTime
      FROM TrainTable
      GROUP BY Train
) r
INNER JOIN TrainTable t
ON t.Train = r.Train AND t.Time = r.MaxTime
```

Result

```
Train    Dest      Time
1        SZ        14:00
2        HK        13:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make with nativequery to run MySQL query directly. It is the easiest and the best way. Please try this:

```
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory mySessionFactory;


    String query ="SELECT t.Train, t.Dest, r.MaxTime "
       +" FROM (SELECT Train, MAX(Time) as MaxTime FROM TrainTable GROUP BY Train) r "
       +" INNER JOIN TrainTable t "
       +" ON t.Train = r.Train AND t.Time = r.MaxTime";

    List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery(query)
                    .getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using hibernate native query in hibernate and its working fine.But I still need to get it done through Criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Given that I don't know the models and theirs relantionship, i think something like this will guide you:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(R.class)
        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("train"), "train")
        .add(Projections.property("dest"), "dest"))
        .add( Projections.groupProperty("train"), "train" )
        .createCriteria("trainTable").add(Projections.max("maxTime"))
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(R.class));

      List<R> list = cr.list();
```

For more info, try reseach at [this tutorial](http://www.devglan.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-tutorial) and [this one too](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/pt-BR/html/querycriteria.html)

Comment: Not working. org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: trainTableof: com.model.TrainTable